# two slider values on same page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put two different sliders on the same page. If I just do the below for one slider, it works:

```
<h3>Strength of Belief</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="oldbelief">
</div>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("oldbelief");
var output = document.getElementById("belief_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

But if I try to do add a second slider with the coding below, the value display on the second does not work:

```
<h3>Strength of Belief</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="oldbelief">
</div>
</div>

<h3><i>New</i> Strength of Belief in Negative Cognition</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief2_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider2" id="newbelief">
</div>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("oldbelief");
var output = document.getElementById("belief_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
var slider2 = document.getElementById("newbelief");
var output2 = document.getElementById("belief2_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

Here is the CSS if it matters:

```
.slider_left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.slider_mid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 79%;
}
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider, .slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #999;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I am new to javascript, so my error is probably pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake here `output.innerHTML = slider.value;` . You should target to `output2` as you created it for second slider.

And your `.slider_left` class on your `CSS` you set color: `#fff` that's why this is another reason text will be white color as same as background and won't be visible

Here you can see below how it should be

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("oldbelief");
var output = document.getElementById("belief_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
var slider2 = document.getElementById("newbelief");
var output2 = document.getElementById("belief2_value");
output2.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slider_left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
}


.slider_mid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 79%;
}
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider, .slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #999;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Strength of Belief</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="oldbelief">
</div>
</div>

<h3><i>New</i> Strength of Belief in Negative Cognition</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_right">
    <span id="belief2_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider2" id="newbelief">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon running it, I didn't see the problem. After adding the css, I noticed that the text did disappear. However, after selecting everything, I figured out the problem: your text was colored `#fff`, which is white. `#000` is black. When I put that in the `color` attribute, it was fixed.

```css
.slider_left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000000;
}


.slider_mid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 79%;
}
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider, .slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #999;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<h3>Strength of Belief</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="oldbelief">
</div>
</div>

<h3><i>New</i> Strength of Belief in Negative Cognition</h3>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slider_left">
    <span id="belief2_value"></span>%
</div>
<div class="slider_mid">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider2" id="newbelief">
</div>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("oldbelief");
var output = document.getElementById("belief_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
var slider2 = document.getElementById("newbelief");
var output2 = document.getElementById("belief2_value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```